# Sum alternate columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like

```
 A   00:00 00:30 01:00 01:30 02:00 .....22:30 23:00 23:30 
 1     2     3     3     4    3            1     6   4
 2     5     6     2     6    5            2     1   2
```

I am trying to get,

```
 A   00:00 01:00 02:00 ..... 23:00
 1     6     6     7           7
 2     7     8     11          3
```

The column `23:30` gets added in `00:00`.

I have tried using [`numpy.sum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) which sums all the columns. How can I tell it to sum every alternate column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
In [261]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,6), columns=['00:00','00:30','01:00','01:30','02:00','02:30'])
df

Out[261]:
      00:00     00:30     01:00     01:30     02:00     02:30
0  0.176952  1.161850  0.894800 -0.246474  1.252235 -0.816835
1  0.817057 -1.338584 -0.983922 -0.073771 -2.188114  1.819888
2 -0.637196 -0.429361  1.267454  0.040461  1.256472 -0.242053
3  0.270544  0.403675  0.890263  1.767279  1.380494 -1.349156
4 -0.752082  0.380903 -0.795439  1.176303  0.176784  0.693317

In [262]:    
rhs = df.ix[:,1::2]
df.ix[:,::2] + pd.concat([rhs.ix[:,-1:],rhs.ix[:,:-1]],axis=1).values

Out[262]:
      00:00     01:00     02:00
0 -0.639884  2.056650  1.005761
1  2.636945 -2.322505 -2.261885
2 -0.879249  0.838093  1.296933
3 -1.078612  1.293938  3.147772
4 -0.058764 -0.414535  1.353087

In [263]:
rhs

Out[263]:
      00:30     01:30     02:30
0  1.161850 -0.246474 -0.816835
1 -1.338584 -0.073771  1.819888
2 -0.429361  0.040461 -0.242053
3  0.403675  1.767279 -1.349156
4  0.380903  1.176303  0.693317
```

So in your case as you have 30 min intervals in your column names then the resulting df will use the hourly interval column names in the lhs and the values from the 30 min intervals and add these values

So here we use slice with step `.ix[:,::2]` to return all rows and step the columns when adding we return a numpy array using `.values` because otherwise you get all `NaN` values as pandas will attempt to align on the column names and you'll get no matches.

As you want to add `00:00` with `23:30` then we can `concat` the last column with the remainder of the columns so we get the column alignment when adding the columns

Comment: Definitely helpful but if you see the first column and the last column gets added up. I think this would not do that.

Comment: See updated answer, this concats the last column with the first to last columns to get the order you desire